# Как понять, куда пропала часть сообщений в топике кафки?

Tags: jmeter, apache-kafka

Отправляю продюсером с генератора нагрузки 10 тысяч сообщений в топик кафки, смотрю на графану, показывает, что отправлено 10 тысяч, в кафке смотрю суммарное кол-во сообщений, и каждый раз чуть чуть не хватает, к примеру 9959 или 9983. В чем может быть проблема и как ее локализовать, и определить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Графана только показывает то, что возвращает [data source](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/), возможно вам стоит проверить ее настройки визуализации а также то, откуда она берет данные
2. Кафка сама по себе очень сложная система и в случае распределенной архитектуры может быть так, что одна реплика получила данные, но они еще не были скопированы на другие реплики или данные в памяти но не на диске.

Я бы для начала посоветовал включить логи DEBUG уровня и в [JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) и в [Kafka](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cloud-paks/cp-biz-automation/19.0.x?topic=emitter-enabling-kafka-broker-trace) и посмотреть нет ли там подозрительных записей.

Что еще можно предпринять:

1. По стороне JMeter:

   - выставить параметер `acks` в `-1`, тогда JMeter будет считать что сообщение доставлено когда все реплики подтвердили получение
   - увеличить значения `retries` и `delivery.timeout.ms`
2. По стороне Kafka

   - увеличить значение `min.insync.replicas` как минимум до 2

Вот неплохая статья которая объясняет возможные причины потери данных: [When you can lose messages in Kafka](https://developer20.com/when-you-can-nose-messages-in-kafka/)